# Counting number of points closest to line (Spatial Join) using ArcPy/ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am trying to get a count of the number of points (join feature) that are closest to each line (target feature) through a spatial join. By going to the table of contents and conducting the spatial join through a right click, spatial join, join all points closest to a line (without checking a feature) - I can achieve the desired result. The desired result is a count field indicating the total number of points closest to every line. However, I have to carry out this process far too many times to do it manually through clicking the spatial join in the table of contents. Thus, I need a way to automate this process to join points to lines and have been attempting to do it using ArcPy.

The ArcPy options seem to work like a spatial join conducted using the toolbox. Which provides options for intersect, closest to, distance etc... however, none of the options function the same way when attempting to join points to lines as the table of contents spatial join does. I cannot use a search distance because it is not uniform across all points and lines to accurately count the number of points closest to each line.

Is there anyway to count the number of points closest to lines using a spatial join process that can be automated in ArcPy or ModelBuilder?

I just the need count.